# Problems w/ e and functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

It's a word problem using atmospheric pressure as an example. Basically it boils down to:
$P(h)$ where $h$ is height
$P'=-kP$ where $k>0$
$P(0)=.7$ and $P(7)=.1$

What is $k$? (I got $k=.277987$, it said this is correct.)

What is $P(10)$? (I got $1.902797$ and it says this is wrong.)

$P(t)=ae^{-kt}$, and I know that comes out to $P(t)=.7e^{-.277987t}$
So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function $\  P(t)=0.7e^{-0.277987\,t}\ $ *strictly decreases* as $\ t\ $ increases. Since $\ P(10)\ $ must therefore be *strictly less than* $\ P(7)=0.1\ $, that already tells you $\ P(10)\ $ can't possibly be $1.902797$. [WolframAlpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.7*e%5E%28-0.277987*10%29) $\ P(10)=$$\,0.7e^{-2.77987}\approx$$\,0.0434326\ $.

Since $\ 0.7e\approx1.902797\ $, it looks like you've used the exponent $\ 1\ $ in the exponential, instead of the correct value of $\ {-}2.77987\ $.